# usb report description parsing

Tags: usb

I try to understand how to find a usb device report length.

with `lsusb -vvv` , there is no information about report description contents or size:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045e:0752 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 400
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
  idProduct          0x0752 Wired Keyboard 400
  bcdDevice            3.00
  iManufacturer           1 Microsoft
  iProduct                2 Wired Keyboard 400
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           34
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      65
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

I then tried to cat rdesc from sys entry:
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/hid/0003:045E:0752.0002/rdesc
and got the following:

```
05 01 09 06 a1 01 05 07 19 e0 29 e7 15 00 25 01 75 01 95 08 81 02 95 01 75 08 81 01 95 05 75 01 05 08 19 01 29 05 91 02 95 01 75 03 91 01 95 06 75 08 15 00 26 ff 00 05 07 19 00 2a ff 00 81 00 c0 

  INPUT[INPUT]
    Field(0)
      Application(GenericDesktop.Keyboard)
      Usage(8)
        Keyboard.00e0
        Keyboard.00e1
        Keyboard.00e2
        Keyboard.00e3
        Keyboard.00e4
        Keyboard.00e5
        Keyboard.00e6
        Keyboard.00e7
      Logical Minimum(0)
      Logical Maximum(1)
      Report Size(1)
      Report Count(8)
      Report Offset(0)
      Flags( Variable Absolute )
    Field(1)
      Application(GenericDesktop.Keyboard)
      Usage(256)
        Keyboard.0000
        Keyboard.0001
        Keyboard.0002
        Keyboard.0003
        Keyboard.0004
        Keyboard.0005
        Keyboard.0006
        Keyboard.0007
        Keyboard.0008
        Keyboard.0009
        Keyboard.000a
        Keyboard.000b
        Keyboard.000c
        Keyboard.000d
        Keyboard.000e
        Keyboard.000f
        Keyboard.0010
        Keyboard.0011
        Keyboard.0012
        Keyboard.0013
        Keyboard.0014
        Keyboard.0015
        Keyboard.0016
        Keyboard.0017
        Keyboard.0018
        Keyboard.0019
        Keyboard.001a
        Keyboard.001b
        Keyboard.001c
        Keyboard.001d
        Keyboard.001e
        Keyboard.001f
        Keyboard.0020
        Keyboard.0021
        Keyboard.0022
        Keyboard.0023
        Keyboard.0024
        Keyboard.0025
        Keyboard.0026
        Keyboard.0027
        Keyboard.0028
        Keyboard.0029
        Keyboard.002a
        Keyboard.002b
        Keyboard.002c
        Keyboard.002d
        Keyboard.002e
        Keyboard.002f
        Keyboard.0030
        Keyboard.0031
        Keyboard.0032
        Keyboard.0033
        Keyboard.0034
        Keyboard.0035
        Keyboard.0036
        Keyboard.0037
        Keyboard.0038
        Keyboard.0039
        Keyboard.003a
        Keyboard.003b
        Keyboard.003c
        Keyboard.003d
        Keyboard.003e
        Keyboard.003f
        Keyboard.0040
        Keyboard.0041
        Keyboard.0042
        Keyboard.0043
        Keyboard.0044
        Keyboard.0045
        Keyboard.0046
        Keyboard.0047
        Keyboard.0048
        Keyboard.0049
        Keyboard.004a
        Keyboard.004b
        Keyboard.004c
        Keyboard.004d
        Keyboard.004e
        Keyboard.004f
        Keyboard.0050
        Keyboard.0051
        Keyboard.0052
        Keyboard.0053
        Keyboard.0054
        Keyboard.0055
        Keyboard.0056
        Keyboard.0057
        Keyboard.0058
        Keyboard.0059
        Keyboard.005a
        Keyboard.005b
        Keyboard.005c
        Keyboard.005d
        Keyboard.005e
        Keyboard.005f
        Keyboard.0060
        Keyboard.0061
        Keyboard.0062
        Keyboard.0063
        Keyboard.0064
        Keyboard.0065
        Keyboard.0066
        Keyboard.0067
        Keyboard.0068
        Keyboard.0069
        Keyboard.006a
        Keyboard.006b
        Keyboard.006c
        Keyboard.006d
        Keyboard.006e
        Keyboard.006f
        Keyboard.0070
        Keyboard.0071
        Keyboard.0072
        Keyboard.0073
        Keyboard.0074
        Keyboard.0075
        Keyboard.0076
        Keyboard.0077
        Keyboard.0078
        Keyboard.0079
        Keyboard.007a
        Keyboard.007b
        Keyboard.007c
        Keyboard.007d
        Keyboard.007e
        Keyboard.007f
        Keyboard.0080
        Keyboard.0081
        Keyboard.0082
        Keyboard.0083
        Keyboard.0084
        Keyboard.0085
        Keyboard.0086
        Keyboard.0087
        Keyboard.0088
        Keyboard.0089
        Keyboard.008a
        Keyboard.008b
        Keyboard.008c
        Keyboard.008d
        Keyboard.008e
        Keyboard.008f
        Keyboard.0090
        Keyboard.0091
        Keyboard.0092
        Keyboard.0093
        Keyboard.0094
        Keyboard.0095
        Keyboard.0096
        Keyboard.0097
        Keyboard.0098
        Keyboard.0099
        Keyboard.009a
        Keyboard.009b
        Keyboard.009c
        Keyboard.009d
        Keyboard.009e
        Keyboard.009f
        Keyboard.00a0
        Keyboard.00a1
        Keyboard.00a2
        Keyboard.00a3
        Keyboard.00a4
        Keyboard.00a5
        Keyboard.00a6
        Keyboard.00a7
        Keyboard.00a8
        Keyboard.00a9
        Keyboard.00aa
        Keyboard.00ab
        Keyboard.00ac
        Keyboard.00ad
        Keyboard.00ae
        Keyboard.00af
        Keyboard.00b0
        Keyboard.00b1
        Keyboard.00b2
        Keyboard.00b3
        Keyboard.00b4
        Keyboard.00b5
        Keyboard.00b6
        Keyboard.00b7
        Keyboard.00b8
        Keyboard.00b9
        Keyboard.00ba
        Keyboard.00bb
        Keyboard.00bc
        Keyboard.00bd
        Keyboard.00be
        Keyboard.00bf
        Keyboard.00c0
        Keyboard.00c1
        Keyboard.00c2
        Keyboard.00c3
        Keyboard.00c4
        Keyboard.00c5
        Keyboard.00c6
        Keyboard.00c7
        Keyboard.00c8
        Keyboard.00c9
        Keyboard.00ca
        Keyboard.00cb
        Keyboard.00cc
        Keyboard.00cd
        Keyboard.00ce
        Keyboard.00cf
        Keyboard.00d0
        Keyboard.00d1
        Keyboard.00d2
        Keyboard.00d3
        Keyboard.00d4
        Keyboard.00d5
        Keyboard.00d6
        Keyboard.00d7
        Keyboard.00d8
        Keyboard.00d9
        Keyboard.00da
        Keyboard.00db
        Keyboard.00dc
        Keyboard.00dd
        Keyboard.00de
        Keyboard.00df
        Keyboard.00e0
        Keyboard.00e1
        Keyboard.00e2
        Keyboard.00e3
        Keyboard.00e4
        Keyboard.00e5
        Keyboard.00e6
        Keyboard.00e7
        Keyboard.00e8
        Keyboard.00e9
        Keyboard.00ea
        Keyboard.00eb
        Keyboard.00ec
        Keyboard.00ed
        Keyboard.00ee
        Keyboard.00ef
        Keyboard.00f0
        Keyboard.00f1
        Keyboard.00f2
        Keyboard.00f3
        Keyboard.00f4
        Keyboard.00f5
        Keyboard.00f6
        Keyboard.00f7
        Keyboard.00f8
        Keyboard.00f9
        Keyboard.00fa
        Keyboard.00fb
        Keyboard.00fc
        Keyboard.00fd
        Keyboard.00fe
        Keyboard.00ff
      Logical Minimum(0)
      Logical Maximum(255)
      Report Size(8)
      Report Count(6)
      Report Offset(16)
      Flags( Array Absolute )
  OUTPUT[OUTPUT]
    Field(0)
      Application(GenericDesktop.Keyboard)
      Usage(5)
        LED.NumLock
        LED.CapsLock
        LED.ScrollLock
        LED.Compose
        LED.Kana
      Logical Minimum(0)
      Logical Maximum(1)
      Report Size(1)
      Report Count(5)
      Report Offset(0)
      Flags( Variable Absolute )

Keyboard.00e0 ---> Key.LeftControl
Keyboard.00e1 ---> Key.LeftShift
Keyboard.00e2 ---> Key.LeftAlt
Keyboard.00e3 ---> Key.LeftMeta
Keyboard.00e4 ---> Key.RightCtrl
Keyboard.00e5 ---> Key.RightShift
Keyboard.00e6 ---> Key.RightAlt
Keyboard.00e7 ---> Key.RightMeta
Keyboard.0000 ---> Sync.Report
Keyboard.0001 ---> Sync.Report
Keyboard.0002 ---> Sync.Report
Keyboard.0003 ---> Sync.Report
Keyboard.0004 ---> Key.A
Keyboard.0005 ---> Key.B
Keyboard.0006 ---> Key.C
Keyboard.0007 ---> Key.D
Keyboard.0008 ---> Key.E
Keyboard.0009 ---> Key.F
Keyboard.000a ---> Key.G
Keyboard.000b ---> Key.H
Keyboard.000c ---> Key.I
Keyboard.000d ---> Key.J
Keyboard.000e ---> Key.K
Keyboard.000f ---> Key.L
Keyboard.0010 ---> Key.M
Keyboard.0011 ---> Key.N
Keyboard.0012 ---> Key.O
Keyboard.0013 ---> Key.P
Keyboard.0014 ---> Key.Q
Keyboard.0015 ---> Key.R
Keyboard.0016 ---> Key.S
Keyboard.0017 ---> Key.T
Keyboard.0018 ---> Key.U
Keyboard.0019 ---> Key.V
Keyboard.001a ---> Key.W
Keyboard.001b ---> Key.X
Keyboard.001c ---> Key.Y
Keyboard.001d ---> Key.Z
Keyboard.001e ---> Key.1
Keyboard.001f ---> Key.2
Keyboard.0020 ---> Key.3
Keyboard.0021 ---> Key.4
Keyboard.0022 ---> Key.5
Keyboard.0023 ---> Key.6
Keyboard.0024 ---> Key.7
Keyboard.0025 ---> Key.8
Keyboard.0026 ---> Key.9
Keyboard.0027 ---> Key.0
Keyboard.0028 ---> Key.Enter
Keyboard.0029 ---> Key.Esc
Keyboard.002a ---> Key.Backspace
Keyboard.002b ---> Key.Tab
Keyboard.002c ---> Key.Space
Keyboard.002d ---> Key.Minus
Keyboard.002e ---> Key.Equal
Keyboard.002f ---> Key.LeftBrace
Keyboard.0030 ---> Key.RightBrace
Keyboard.0031 ---> Key.BackSlash
Keyboard.0032 ---> Key.BackSlash
Keyboard.0033 ---> Key.Semicolon
Keyboard.0034 ---> Key.Apostrophe
Keyboard.0035 ---> Key.Grave
Keyboard.0036 ---> Key.Comma
Keyboard.0037 ---> Key.Dot
Keyboard.0038 ---> Key.Slash
Keyboard.0039 ---> Key.CapsLock
Keyboard.003a ---> Key.F1
Keyboard.003b ---> Key.F2
Keyboard.003c ---> Key.F3
Keyboard.003d ---> Key.F4
Keyboard.003e ---> Key.F5
Keyboard.003f ---> Key.F6
Keyboard.0040 ---> Key.F7
Keyboard.0041 ---> Key.F8
Keyboard.0042 ---> Key.F9
Keyboard.0043 ---> Key.F10
Keyboard.0044 ---> Key.F11
Keyboard.0045 ---> Key.F12
Keyboard.0046 ---> Key.SysRq
Keyboard.0047 ---> Key.ScrollLock
Keyboard.0048 ---> Key.Pause
Keyboard.0049 ---> Key.Insert
Keyboard.004a ---> Key.Home
Keyboard.004b ---> Key.PageUp
Keyboard.004c ---> Key.Delete
Keyboard.004d ---> Key.End
Keyboard.004e ---> Key.PageDown
Keyboard.004f ---> Key.Right
Keyboard.0050 ---> Key.Left
Keyboard.0051 ---> Key.Down
Keyboard.0052 ---> Key.Up
Keyboard.0053 ---> Key.NumLock
Keyboard.0054 ---> Key.KPSlash
Keyboard.0055 ---> Key.KPAsterisk
Keyboard.0056 ---> Key.KPMinus
Keyboard.0057 ---> Key.KPPlus
Keyboard.0058 ---> Key.KPEnter
Keyboard.0059 ---> Key.KP1
Keyboard.005a ---> Key.KP2
Keyboard.005b ---> Key.KP3
Keyboard.005c ---> Key.KP4
Keyboard.005d ---> Key.KP5
Keyboard.005e ---> Key.KP6
Keyboard.005f ---> Key.KP7
Keyboard.0060 ---> Key.KP8
Keyboard.0061 ---> Key.KP9
Keyboard.0062 ---> Key.KP0
Keyboard.0063 ---> Key.KPDot
Keyboard.0064 ---> Key.102nd
Keyboard.0065 ---> Key.Compose
Keyboard.0066 ---> Key.Power
Keyboard.0067 ---> Key.KPEqual
Keyboard.0068 ---> Key.F13
Keyboard.0069 ---> Key.F14
Keyboard.006a ---> Key.F15
Keyboard.006b ---> Key.F16
Keyboard.006c ---> Key.F17
Keyboard.006d ---> Key.F18
Keyboard.006e ---> Key.F19
Keyboard.006f ---> Key.F20
Keyboard.0070 ---> Key.F21
Keyboard.0071 ---> Key.F22
Keyboard.0072 ---> Key.F23
Keyboard.0073 ---> Key.F24
Keyboard.0074 ---> Key.Open
Keyboard.0075 ---> Key.Help
Keyboard.0076 ---> Key.Props
Keyboard.0077 ---> Key.Front
Keyboard.0078 ---> Key.Stop
Keyboard.0079 ---> Key.Again
Keyboard.007a ---> Key.Undo
Keyboard.007b ---> Key.Cut
Keyboard.007c ---> Key.Copy
Keyboard.007d ---> Key.Paste
Keyboard.007e ---> Key.Find
Keyboard.007f ---> Key.Mute
Keyboard.0080 ---> Key.VolumeUp
Keyboard.0081 ---> Key.VolumeDown
Keyboard.0082 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0083 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0084 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0085 ---> Key.KPComma
Keyboard.0086 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0087 ---> Key.RO
Keyboard.0088 ---> Key.Katakana/Hiragana
Keyboard.0089 ---> Key.Yen
Keyboard.008a ---> Key.Henkan
Keyboard.008b ---> Key.Muhenkan
Keyboard.008c ---> Key.KPJpComma
Keyboard.008d ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.008e ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.008f ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0090 ---> Key.Hangeul
Keyboard.0091 ---> Key.Hanja
Keyboard.0092 ---> Key.Katakana
Keyboard.0093 ---> Key.HIRAGANA
Keyboard.0094 ---> Key.Zenkaku/Hankaku
Keyboard.0095 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0096 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0097 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0098 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0099 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.009a ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.009b ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.009c ---> Key.Delete
Keyboard.009d ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.009e ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.009f ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00a0 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00a1 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00a2 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00a3 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00a4 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00a5 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00a6 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00a7 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00a8 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00a9 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00aa ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00ab ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00ac ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00ad ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00ae ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00af ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00b0 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00b1 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00b2 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00b3 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00b4 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00b5 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00b6 ---> Key.KPLeftParenthesis
Keyboard.00b7 ---> Key.KPRightParenthesis
Keyboard.00b8 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00b9 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00ba ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00bb ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00bc ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00bd ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00be ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00bf ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00c0 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00c1 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00c2 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00c3 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00c4 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00c5 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00c6 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00c7 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00c8 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00c9 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00ca ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00cb ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00cc ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00cd ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00ce ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00cf ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00d0 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00d1 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00d2 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00d3 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00d4 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00d5 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00d6 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00d7 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00d8 ---> Key.Delete
Keyboard.00d9 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00da ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00db ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00dc ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00dd ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00de ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00df ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00e0 ---> Key.LeftControl
Keyboard.00e1 ---> Key.LeftShift
Keyboard.00e2 ---> Key.LeftAlt
Keyboard.00e3 ---> Key.LeftMeta
Keyboard.00e4 ---> Key.RightCtrl
Keyboard.00e5 ---> Key.RightShift
Keyboard.00e6 ---> Key.RightAlt
Keyboard.00e7 ---> Key.RightMeta
Keyboard.00e8 ---> Key.PlayPause
Keyboard.00e9 ---> Key.StopCD
Keyboard.00ea ---> Key.PreviousSong
Keyboard.00eb ---> Key.NextSong
Keyboard.00ec ---> Key.EjectCD
Keyboard.00ed ---> Key.VolumeUp
Keyboard.00ee ---> Key.VolumeDown
Keyboard.00ef ---> Key.Mute
Keyboard.00f0 ---> Key.WWW
Keyboard.00f1 ---> Key.Back
Keyboard.00f2 ---> Key.Forward
Keyboard.00f3 ---> Key.Stop
Keyboard.00f4 ---> Key.Find
Keyboard.00f5 ---> Key.ScrollUp
Keyboard.00f6 ---> Key.ScrollDown
Keyboard.00f7 ---> Key.Edit
Keyboard.00f8 ---> Key.Sleep
Keyboard.00f9 ---> Key.Coffee
Keyboard.00fa ---> Key.Refresh
Keyboard.00fb ---> Key.Calc
Keyboard.00fc ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00fd ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00fe ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00ff ---> Key.Unknown
LED.NumLock ---> LED.NumLock
LED.CapsLock ---> LED.CapsLock
LED.ScrollLock ---> LED.ScrollLock
LED.Compose ---> LED.Compose
LED.Kana ---> LED.Kana
```

According to my understanding how to parse it it is 1+6 bytes = 7 bytes, is that correct ?

I then also made a small application which reads from /dev/hidraw1 of my keyboard, and see that it always reads 8 bytes !

Is it that I parsed the report descriptor incorrectly ?

Thanks,
ranran

Comment: Did you run the `lsusb -vvv` command as root? Report descriptors are not available as normal users. Still some descriptors are unavailable even as root.

Comment: IIRC the first byte is the index number of the report, so you get 8 bytes in total. But I'll have to look this up in my notes to confirm.

Comment: Right, I noticed that also later. You can put is an answer.